# SFML window resizing events blocking the main thread

Tags: windows, opengl, resize, sfml

I just started using the [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org) library and its fantastic. However when resizing a window by dragging the corner with my mouse i don't get the resize events until i release the mouse. This means i can't update my graphics until the mouse is released (game loop is on the gui thread) and is also causing a massive flood of events to come through of all the resize positions.

How can i make it so resizing doesn't block the thread?

Answer (score 3):

Windows causes this. GetEvent() becomes blocking if you move or resize the window.
(Another funny little reason to hate this OS...)

I have solved this with a separate event-polling thread. Take a look at this:
(The interesting part for you is entirely in main.cpp.)

https://bitbucket.org/torokati44/netframework/src/93bdf20d0f65/main.cpp

Comment: Why do you use 2 event queues (event_buffer_a, event_buffer_b)? And why do you use std::queue instead of std::vector?

Comment: This is called double buffering. Well... I'm not sure if it's really necessary after all, but it works now, and I have more important things to polish in this porject, so I don't mess with it right now. Yes, it can be done with only one buffer. The reason I made two might be that I thought the insertion would block, but only the GetEvent blocks, so the insertion after that is OK. Also, I don't think they have to be deque, queue would be enough.

And I use queue because it's faster to pop/push than vector, because that's a linked list, and not a "C-style array" in the background.